# couldn't find db file in users directory in IPhone simulator

Tags: iphone, ios5, sqlite, ios-simulator

In my mac, i am using XCode 4.2 with iOS 5 sdk and Mac OS X 10.7.2 version.

I am developing the application which based on Sqlite database so i can insert, select and delete data from that database.

when i running my application in simulator, i can see the database path in NSLog but i couldn't access the database through into that directory.

DB path which i got in log is ==> /Users/username/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/3623C505-F568-4B18-986E-F2C7D71D5079/Documents/SqlUser.sqlite

I couldn't see Library directory in /username folder. So i can't access the db file.

but in Mac OS X 10.6.8 version with Xcode 3.2.5 iOS 4.2, i can see the Library directory in /username folder. Why this is not possible in 10.7.2?

Please help in this regards!!!

Thanks!!!

Comment: I'm on 10.7.2 and I see /Users/{username}/Library folder.  I don't think your issue is OS version dependent

Comment: but in my system, i couldn't find that Library folder.. How to make it possible?

Comment: which OS version to use?
and it may be problem that by default "Library" folder is hidden so that select Finder =>Go => Go To Folder and paste the path of the "/Users/username/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Open your console and write:

```
chflags nohidden ~/Library/
```

hit enter and browse...

ta da!